# VBA search for string in a specific column in two sheets, and delete if found

Tags: excel, vba

hope someone can help me fix this code. Want to look for a string "StringName" in column F (the string will always be in column F). I have tried to make an array of the two sheets, and then loop through them and find the string i want to delete. If the string is found in one or both of the sheets, then the entire row should be deleted.

I want to do this with 4 more strings, and havent thought on how to do it yet. Would it be better to just find the strings i need to keep which is "hello" and "goodbye", and then say everything that doesn't match those two string, delete? Hope someone can help

```
Sub test1()

    Dim sheetArray As Variant
    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim targetCell As Range

    sheetArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    For Each ws In sheetArray
        With Worksheets(ws)
            For Each targetCell In Range("F:F")
                If InStr(targetCell, "StringName") Then
                    targetCell.EntireRow.delete
                End If
            Next targetCell
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You could have another loop to go through the search terms. More importantly though if deleting rows you must loop backwards. And use `Find` rather than looping through a million cells.

Comment: It's also often far more efficient to sort then filter ranges for the desired values and then delete the visible rows, rather than looping through all rows.

Comment: Ah i understand, thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `If ... And ...`  or `If ... Or ...`.
Example below, I went for just keeping 'hello' and 'goodbye' as you suggest because the code's shorter/simpler that way.

```
Sub answer1()
Dim sheetArray As Variant, ws As Worksheet, a As Long

sheetArray = Array(Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2"))

For Each ws In sheetArray
    With ws
        For a = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + UsedRange.Row -1 to .UsedRange.Row step -1 'counting backwards/upwards because we're deleting rows, counting forward/down would end up skipping some rows.
            If Not .Cells(a, 6) Like "*hello*" _
            And Not .Cells(a, 6) Like "*goodbye*" Then 'the 6 refers to column F
                .Rows(a).Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With 'ws
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me an error which says "For Each control variable must be Variant or Object"

Comment: It works when i just change ws to a variant-type instead of string-type. Thank you so much! Can the code still work if i want to keep 3 strings? Can i just add another "And not"?

Comment: Yes the code will still work if you add another `And Not` - if you're adding more than say 5 though, I'd consider creating a loop to do that bit instead rather than a massive If statement.

Comment: I have also just edited the 'For' loop to make it compensate for 'Usedrange' doesn't start at row 1 - as per somebody's comment that just got deleted idk why, 'UsedRange' isn't 100% reliable and bombproof, but I've always found it plenty good enough for my needs.

Comment: Perfect because my header row, which was in row 1, got deleted. So made a work-around macro, but its bad fixing macro problems with a new macro haha. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: But the problem is now in my line with "For a = ....". It says "object required". I have changed ws to a variant again and it somehow fails in that line.

Comment: Change `ws As String` to `ws As Worksheet`.
then change so that `SheetArray = Array(Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")`
Then finally change `With Worksheets(ws)` to `With ws`

Comment: Or just copy my updated code ;)

Comment: Well i have just tried to copy and paste it into my VBA file. The error is still "Object required". But now the error is in the line "For each ws in sheetArray" And not in the body

Comment: Nevermind fixed it myself. Just changed the "To 1 Step -1" to "To 2 Step -1". And now it doesnt delete my first header row :)

Answer (score 0):

I used autofilter and delete rows the visible rows. if there is no header, no need of offset. I used string doesn't match criteria in sheet1 and string match criteria in Sheet2 in the code

```
 Sub autofilter_Remove()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Rng1, Rng2 As Range
    
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Set Rng1 = ws1.Rows(1)
    Set Rng2 = ws2.Rows(1)
    
    Stringname = "hello"
    
    '6 for F column
    Rng1.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>*" & Stringname & "*"
    
    ws1.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
        (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        
    ws1.Cells.AutoFilter
    
    
    Rng2.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="*" & Stringname & "*"
    
    ws2.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
        (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        
    ws2.Cells.AutoFilter
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: So if i would like to keep two strings "hello" and "goodbye", then i would need a stringname2 and do the same as you have done for each sheet?

Comment: you can have multiple criteria ,Criteria1:=Array("hello","good")

Comment: Ah okay cool, thank you!